# Using multiple SQL databases in the same web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a web application developed in ASP MVC5.0 using Entity Framework 6.1.3. This is a site meant for a client. Everything has been working fine, but now a new scenario has arisen. Another client is gonna use this application side by side. There is no scope for hosting another application with another DB (which is quite simple). About 100 master tables are there with multiple joins to other tables altogether 250+ tables.
The main issue is there is no client identifier in any table and we cannot get that now since this would be a nightmare adding client ids in all tables as well as the queries and stored procs.

We have come up with a possible solution to add another DB to the site and boarding the new client in that.

There is one connection string with name "EFDBContext" in the config file, which drives the application. 
I would like to add another connection string (more might come in as more clients can join) in the webconfig We cant figure out how this can be achieved.
So when one client logs in to the main DB, his session should be redirected to his corresponding database.

Can anybody show some light on this, whether possible or any workaround ?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you will be spinning up a new instance of both the database and the application (web) code.

In this scenario, simply change the connectionstring for each instance o the deployed code.
I would NOT recommend adding a connectionstring per client.

If you are using a single code deployment with multiple databases, then you will need some kind of mapping between users and databases.. which sounds really dumb.  How will you know which database to authenticate against?

Anyhow.. assuming you have such a mapping, then you would indeed add new connectionstrings to the web.config...

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Client1" connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

    <add name="Client2" connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

and then select the correct string...

```
public class SiteDatabase: DbContext {
    public SiteDatabase() : base(_userToDatabaseMap[user]) { }
}
```

If you have not built multi-tenancy into your application, you should definitely deploy a separate database and code for each client.